# What's the best was to addEventListener onclick to the timer that I already have in place?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Apologies for the beginner question, I'm brushing up on my JS and this is my first post on here. I'm trying to add an event listener to this JS timer that's connected to my button .start-timer. What's the best way to go about it? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
const timeH = document.querySelector('h2');
let timeSecond = 30;

timeH.innerHTML = `${timeSecond}`;


const countdown = setInterval (()=>{
 timeSecond --;
 timeH.innerHTML = `${timeSecond}`;   
 if(timeSecond <= 0 || timeSecond < 1){
    clearInterval(countdown);
 }
},1000)
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding an event  listener?

Comment: There is no element with a `start-timer` class.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 functions to `start` and `stop` which only `setInterval` or `clearInterval` nothing special.

```js
const timeH = document.querySelector('h2');
let timeSecond = 30;

timeH.innerHTML = `${timeSecond}`;

var countdown;

function start() {
  clearInterval(countdown);
  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    timeSecond -= 0.1;
    timeH.innerHTML = `${timeSecond.toFixed(1)}`;
    if (timeSecond <= 0 || timeSecond < 1) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
  }, 100)
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(countdown);
}

document.querySelector(".start-timer").addEventListener('click', start);

document.querySelector(".stop-timer").addEventListener('click', stop);
```

```html
<h2>hello</h2>
<button class="start-timer">start-timer</button>
<button class="stop-timer">stop-timer</button>
```